# Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have months stored in SQL Server as 1,2,3,4,...12. I would like to display them as January,February etc. Is there a function in SQL Server like MonthName(1) = January? I am trying to avoid a CASE statement, if possible.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

A little hacky but should work:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mydate-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))
```

Comment: Why the '-1'? Is that needed because the months in SQL Server are offset by one?

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 it's actually because the date that's being used to seed the dateadd function starts at 1.  if we need January's datename, we would be adding 1 month to 2008-01-01, which would give us 2008-02-01, which is February.  so we subtract 1 to account for this, and we get January again.

Comment: To get around the problem of subtracting 1 from your datetime, use a datetime in December as opposed to January.  For example SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mydate, CAST('1978-12-01' AS datetime)))

Comment: This is a good piece of information, but fails to actually answer the question of how to convert a month number to a month name (Rather answers how to get a month name from a date). You've assumed that he has the datetime value rather than just the month number; to get this to work you now need to 'invent' a date/time value. Think the solution from leoinfo was a bit more relevant

Answer (score 335):

I think this is the best way to get the **month name** when you have the **month number**

```
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )
```

Or

```
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , -1 ) )
```

Comment: for readability purposes I would actually write it like this: Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber  - 1 , '1900-01-01' ) )

Comment: one possible alternative solution Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , -1 ))

Comment: That's perfect. This should be the answer.

Comment: The simpler the better!

Answer (score 109):

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

Comment: Its is getting month name by date not month number, as SO asked.

Comment: How is this getting up votes?

Answer (score 88):

```
SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (@intMonth * 4) - 3, 3)
```

Comment: I like this very left-field alternative way of thinkng!  Food for thought

Comment: And it's deterministic! Can be used as computed column too, thanks!

Comment: nice... i was looking for some simple code to get months from jan to [#] and this worked great. for displaying several months, just change to something like this>>

SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ',0, (@intMonth * 4))

Comment: I definitely wouldn't think of this as the "right way," but it's a fun way that could be used to solve other problems.

Comment: This saved me a tonne of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

**Use the Best way**

```
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , -1 ))
```

Answer (score 20):

It is very simple.

```
select DATENAME(month, getdate())
```

output : January

Comment: This only works if you have a full date value, not a month integer.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. He is asking how to implement  a function like MonthName(1).

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month? Why is this being upvoted?

Answer (score 17):

Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can use **[FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)** and **[DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)** to solve this problem.  (If you want month names from other cultures, change: `en-US`)

```
select FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, @month_num, 1), 'MMMM', 'en-US')
```

If you want a three-letter month:

```
select FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, @month_num, 1), 'MMM', 'en-US')
```

If you really want to, you can create a function for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_month_num_to_name
(
    @month_num tinyint
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, @month_num, 1), 'MMMM', 'en-US')
END
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: It's probably not the most efficient, but it's probably the most easily readable.

Comment: It even supports localization!.. sweet!

Comment: @RosdiKasim I've been bit too many times by hard-coded manual date formatting with different localizations.

Answer (score 9):

You can use  the inbuilt `CONVERT` function

```
select CONVERT(varchar(3), Date, 100)  as Month from MyTable.
```

This will display first 3 characters of month (JAN,FEB etc..)

Answer (score 7):

in addition to original

`SELECT DATENAME(m, str(2) + '/1/2011')`

you can do this

`SELECT DATENAME(m, str([column_name]) + '/1/2011')`

this way you get names for all rows in a table. where [column_name] represents a integer column containing numeric value 1 through 12

2 represents any integer, by contact string i created a date where i can extract the month. '/1/2011' can be any date

if you want to do this with variable

```
DECLARE @integer int;

SET @integer = 6;

SELECT DATENAME(m, str(@integer) + '/1/2011')
```

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS CHAR(3))
```

Comment: How is GETDATE() a integer representing a month?

Answer (score 6):

In some locales like Hebrew, there are [leap months](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_months) dependant upon the year so to avoid errors in such locales you might consider the following solution:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, STR(YEAR(GETDATE()), 4) + REPLACE(STR(@month, 2), ' ', '0') + '01')
```

Comment: Is there a function to convert a date to a Jewish date in SQL? Not that I know of...

Comment: function to convert to Jewish date:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gerireshef/2011/03/29/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%AA-tsql/

Answer (score 5):

**Use this statement to convert Month numeric value to Month name.**

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this is not using an integer, as the OP asked.

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month? Why is this being upvoted?

Answer (score 5):

Just subtract the current month from today's date, then add back your month number.  Then use the datename function to give the full name all in 1 line.

```
print datename(month,dateadd(month,-month(getdate()) + 9,getdate()))
```

Comment: So 9 would be the month as an integer?

Comment: Yes, 9 represents the desired month as an integer.  If you use the integer "4", the line of code returns "April".

Answer (score 4):

Sure this will work

```
select datename(M,GETDATE())
```

Comment: SELECT datename(month, '2017/08/25') AS month_name;

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DateName(M, DateAdd(M, @MONTHNUMBER, -1))
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert month number to month name, try the below

```
declare @month smallint = 1
select DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,@month - 1,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the convert functin as below

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()), 100)
```

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month?

Answer (score 2):

i think this is enough to get month name when u have date.

```
SELECT DATENAME(month ,GETDATE())
```

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,dateadd(month, -3,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
@MetricMonthNumber (some number)

SELECT 
(DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MetricMonthNumber - 1 , '1900-01-01' ) )) AS MetricMonthName
FROM TableName
```

From a post above from @leoinfo and @Valentino Vranken.  Just did a quick select and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @MonthNumber int
SET @MonthNumber=DatePart(Month,GETDATE())
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )
```

Explaination:

1. First Decalre Variable `MonthNumber`
2. Get Current Month for `DatePart` which Return Month Number
3. Third Query Return Month Name

Answer (score 1):

```
select monthname(curdate());
```

OR

```
select monthname('2013-12-12');
```

Comment: How is GETDATE() an integer representing a month?

Answer (score 1):

Working for me

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(<fieldname>) AS "Month Name" FROM <tablename> WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: syntax error. plus <fieldname> cannot be a date or datetime. It must be an integer. Which would result in Jan

Answer (score 1):

you can get the date like this. 
eg:- **Users** table

```
id name created_at
1  abc  2017-09-16
2  xyz  2017-06-10
```

you can get the monthname like this

```
select year(created_at), monthname(created_at) from users;
```

output

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+
| year(created_at) | monthname(created_at)  |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|      2017        | september              |
|      2017        | june                   |
```

Comment: You can find documentation in here.
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php

Comment: the OP asked for sql-server not mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this to generate the Month and do
SELECT dbo.fn_GetMonthFromDate(date_column) as Month FROM table_name

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_GetMonthFromDate]    Script Date: 11/16/2018 10:26:33 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetMonthFromDate] 
(@date datetime)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @monthPart int
```

SET @monthPart = MONTH(@date)

IF @monthPart = 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'January'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 2
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'February'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 3
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'March'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 4
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'April'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 5
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'May'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 6
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'June'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 7
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'July'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 8
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'August'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 9
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'September'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 10
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'October'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 11
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'November'
    END
ELSE IF @monthPart = 12
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'December'
    END
RETURN NULL END

Comment: Would use a case statement. But at least this is using month as an integer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using some information from others to solve a problem.

```
datename(month,dateadd(month,datepart(month,Help_HelpMain.Ticket_Closed_Date),-1)) as monthname
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no system defined function in SQL server. But you can create your own user-defined function- a scalar function. You would find scalar functions in the Object Explorer for your database: Programmability->Functions->Scalar-valued Functions. Below, I use a table variable to bring it all together.

```
--Create the user-defined function
CREATE FUNCTION getmonth (@num int)
RETURNS varchar(9) --since 'September' is the longest string, length 9
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @intMonth Table (num int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), month varchar(9))

INSERT INTO @intMonth VALUES ('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May')
                           , ('June'), ('July'), ('August') ,('September'), ('October')
                           , ('November'), ('December')

RETURN (SELECT I.month
        FROM @intMonth I
        WHERE I.num = @num)
END
GO

--Use the function for various months
SELECT dbo.getmonth(4) AS [Month]
SELECT dbo.getmonth(5) AS [Month]
SELECT dbo.getmonth(6) AS [Month]
```

Comment: Inline table valued function plz?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING('January  February March    April    May      June     July     August   SeptemberOctober  November December ', @MonthNumber * 9 - 8,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server nowadays can get the ordinalnummer of a comma separated value of values, using the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function

Also the names of the month are already stored in SQL Server (use: `SELECT month FROM sys.syslanguages`)

Converting the number of the month to the name of the month can be done by joining to this result

```
select value, ordinal 
from sys.syslanguages 
cross apply string_split(months,',',1) 
where name='Nederlands'
```

output:

| value | ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| januari | 1 |
| februari | 2 |
| maart | 3 |
| april | 4 |
| mei | 5 |
| juni | 6 |
| juli | 7 |
| augustus | 8 |
| september | 9 |
| oktober | 10 |
| november | 11 |
| december | 12 |

see, for other languages than Dutch: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/TOFGJhaM)

Answer (score -1):

```
to_char(to_date(V_MONTH_NUM,'MM'),'MONTH')
```

where `V_MONTH_NUM` is the month number

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(V_MONTH_NUM,'MM'),'MONTH')  from dual;
```

Comment: This looks like it's referring to Oracle. The post is tagged with SQL 2005.

Answer (score -1):

Use this statement for getting month name:

```
DECLARE @date datetime
SET @date='2015/1/4 00:00:00'

SELECT CAST(DATENAME(month,@date )  AS CHAR(3))AS 'Month Name'
```

This will give you short month name. Like this: Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

Comment: How is @date an integer representing a month?

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `SELECT MONTHNAME(concat('1970-',[Month int val],'-01'))`

For example- `SELECT MONTHNAME(concat('1970-',4,'-01'))`

The answer is - April

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is trying to get the same kind of thing in MySQL. please check below query.

```
 SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('November', '%M'))
```

By this I got required result.

Answer (score -2):

Use this statement

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_date,'dd MONTH yyyy') FROM dual
```

this will convert the month number to month full string

Comment: TO_CHAR() is an Oracle function.  The OP is using SQL Server, which has the different but equivalent CONVERT function.