# Month name in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Hi ....

how can i get month name by passing corresponding month number in sql server 2008 ..

thnks in advance....

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Comment: The month name in what language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, <fieldname>) AS "Month Name" FROM <tablename>
```

**Ex:**

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, JoinDate) AS "Month Name" FROM EMPLOYEE
```

This value would return the **monthname** corresponding to the date value in the field **JoinDate** from the table `EMPLOYEE`.