# Getting MonthAndYear name in sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a small script to get the current month name and current year. So as to create a unique batch to store statements. My preferred format is January2011 or Feb2011 whichever is easier to get. i.e. MonthYear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()), DATENAME(year, GETDATE());
```

You can find some more information over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: This would match the preferred format: SELECT DATENAME(month,GETDATE()) + DATENAME(year, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function and combine that with finding the name of a month, [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql) has information on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
select datename(month,getdate()) + cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4))
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket before the `as char(4)`