# How Convert specific String To Month Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Example:
my database table data is 201201 which  i want to display as 2012 DECEMBER . Please advice me. SQL 2005 Environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Comment: how did `201201` became 2012 DECEMBER?

Comment: It should be 2012 JANUARY ???

Comment: haha, sorry,ya,should be january

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @DT DATETIME
SET @DT = CONVERT(DATETIME,'201201' + '01')

SELECT  CAST(YEAR(@DT) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, @DT) AS [Month YYYY]
```

Comment: why need add '01' for CONVERT(DATETIME,'201201' + '01')?not understand

Comment: Yes, to convert DATETIME, string should be complete date string YYYYMMDD, that's why '01' is added.

Comment: +1  I think you could shorten this a bit if you used `DATENAME` for the year as well, and avoided the `cast as varchar(4)`.

Comment: No. YEAR function return integer. So CAST is needed. DATENAME return nvarchar.

Comment: [This is what I'm suggesting.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61214)

Comment: is that othey way direct convert 1 to January.