# Get local time month name in TextBox

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I wrote this SSRS expression to get the month name, it gives the month name in English, but 
I want to get the Local Time or specific culture month name.

How to solve in SSRS?

```
MonthName(Month(Today()))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Comment: Your question is very unclear: are you asking how to do this in Reporting Services, not in TSQL? If so, I suggest you remove the various SQL tags, because they are not relevant. Unless of course you want the database to work out the month name for you?

Comment: @Pondlife,yes i asking in reporting services,@abatishchev edited my tag,he added.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATENAME`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx):

> The return value depends on the language environment set by using SET LANGUAGE and by the Configure the default language Server Configuration Option of the login.

Comment: thanks @abatishchev,but ssrs doesnt allow datename expression in textbox expressions.it give to failure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example i used in my project , hope it helps you as well
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33355/Localization-of-SSRS-Reports

Comment: @bhunpedra,i added in code,<Language>tr-TR</Language> problem is solved