# Should i change attributes in time dimension or create new dimension?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, hierarchy, dimensions

i have a cube which i would like to extract data from. The cube includes a Date-dimension with a hierarchy (year-quarter-month-day), but the months are only represented as integers. I would like to "change" thoose to real month-names. Can i do that in the existing cube or do i have to create new a new time dimension?

EDIT:
So i have created a new time dimension with the simple "create new dimension"-wizard, but the language is english, how can i change this by simplest means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that to an existing cube. In your data source view, a field containing the label will have to be added to the table or named query that acts as source to your time dimension. You'll have to investigate how your source data is provided, though. Easiest would be to create a view on top of your existing structure.

Once you have the label available, modify the month attribute of your time dimension and set the label as NameColumn.

Comment: I alreay have a dsv with a date-table which is a named query. If i want to add to that named query i need to create a new table with my names and then add them, and then fix the label stuff inside the dimension?

Comment: You can use SQL expressions in a named query. When it's added to the DSV, the attribute will be available in your dimension designer.

Comment: I dont really follow.. How can i create the month name in the dsv without making them in a table below first?

Comment: Preferably, you would persist the name of the month, but you can also determine it using a SQL expression, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql