# Show month names against Numeric Values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
ProjectName         MonthsThisYear    CompletionDate
ProjectA                  5               5/1/2013
ProjectB                  7               7/15/2013
ProjectC                 10              10/21/2013
```

I want to bar plot a graph where Y axis is project Name and X axis is January 2013, February 2013 ... December 2013.

Now the bar against projectA must be 5 units long, ProjectB is 7 units long and the bar for Project C should be 10 units long.

so that people can see that ProjectA is completed in May, ProjectB is completed in July and project C in October.

How can I plot this graph?

currently I can plot this correctly... but the X-Asix has 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 on it rather than month names.

I am on SSRS 2008 R2.

This is what I see right now

[image]

I just want to see month names and year on X axis.

Comment: Will the date range always be for a particular year? If so, is there any chance you could this year as a field to the dataset, i.e. each row has a year field with 2013?

Comment: Also, what should the label at *0* be?

Comment: You can use `DateName(month , DateAdd(month , @MonthNumber , -1))`  to convert your x-axis into month-name. function taken from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Comment: Edit your dataset and create a new field `monthName` using the above function. Then use `MonthsThisYear` as your category but in the label show the `monthName` instead of `monthsThisYear`. You can mask the 0 to show as blank. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some more question detail would be useful, but here's one way that works with your data:

[image]

The main issue we're facing is that typically a date is the category, but in this case it's actually the Data value, which gives us less control over the labels compared to a category group.

First, set up a chart with a Category Group based on `ProjectName`, and a Data expression like:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Fields!CompletionDate.Value), Month(Fields!CompletionDate.Value), 1)
```

i.e. the first of the month of each `CompletionDate` value, otherwise your bars will be between months.

[image]

Next, we need to sort out the X axis:

[image]

In my example I set **Minimum** to:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month
  , -1
  , DateSerial(Year(Min(Fields!CompletionDate.Value)), 1, 1))
```

i.e. December for the last year. Set **Maximum** to:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Max(Fields!CompletionDate.Value)), 12, 31)
```

i.e. the end of the year.

Set Interval to `1` and Interval Type to `Months`.

Format the X Axis to `MMM yyyy`.

Looks OK:

[image]

If you can actually add a `Year` column with a value *2013* or whatever, pretty much all of the expressions above can be simplified. For example, I've ignored `MonthsThisYear`, but if you have a `Year` column you can build the start of the month value based on `MonthsThisYear` and `Year`.