# Sql query help, grabbing dates, counts, averages

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `payhistory`, and from this table I need to grab the `Year`, `Month` when a payment was made. I then need to get an average of payments grouped by Year and then month.

```
select AVG(totalpaid) from payhistory
```

This table has a column called `datepaid` that is where I need to grab the date from. It has a column called `totalpaid` which is where I need to grab the average from.

I then need a count of every payment within that month.

And finally a column displaying which Year/Month it was from.

Important columns in the table:

- `number` (account number can use this to get a count)
- `datepaid` (contains the date the payment was entered '2009-09-28 00:00:00.000')
- `totalpaid` (contains the specific payment for that date)

Comment: What **datatypes** are your important columns?

Comment: @marc_s number would be int, datepaid datetime and toldpaid should be money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
select AVG(totalpaid),
   COUNT(number),
   MONTH(datepaid),
   YEAR(datepaid)
from payhistory
group by 
   MONTH(datepaid),
   YEAR(datepaid)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the first column say the Year/Month name?

Comment: @JamesWilson -- Assuming you want to display the month name and not the month number, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/188390/2480596