# how to create monthly reports from daily based reports using sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table contains columns cost,date,customer-id,products bought
i can create daily reports but now i want to create monthly reports as sum of cost.
i have a grid view to show it please explain me clearly am a beginner to this .net 
what should be done in grid view and what should be the sql query
i am using grid view manually generated columns daily basis are customer-id,date,cost,products bought

for monthly reports

i am using grid-view columns cutomerid,month,year,cost

what should be the sql query

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not .net, but SQL. Write the query first, displaying it in your app will phase 2. Do you have reporting services?

```
Select sum(cost), [Month], [Year], customer-id from 
( 
   Select cost, Month(date) as [Month], Year(date) as [Year] , customer-id
   from customerbooking where date >= '2-1-2014' and date <= '2-28-2014'
) as a
Group by [Month], [Year], customer-id
```

Comment: i dont know how to use report services can't we do this through sql server it may not be the easiest way please can you explain what should be sql query

Comment: report builder is easier than this. What is your table name?

Comment: -1: so far, this is a set of comments, not the answer to the question.

Comment: I'm removing the downvote, but, in the future, please don't start the answer until you have enough information to answer with.

Comment: And, BTW, take a close look at that query, and I'm sure you'll find some fairly obvious improvements.

Comment: i got it right but now i want to display month name instead of month number how to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql