# Case Statement in SQL giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query which will give output as MONTH, YEAR.

When I write :

```
 select CAST( tbl.MONTH as varchar(2) ) + ', ' + CAST ( tbl.YEAR as varchar(4) ) as [DATE] 
 from TABLE as tbl
```

I get the output as

```
    1,2014
    4,2014 (depending upon the input)
```

But, Now, I want to replace 1 with JAN, 4 with APRIL 12 with DEC

So, I tried to write a case statement as :

```
SELECT 
    case when tbl.MONTH ='1' 
    then ('JAN' + ', ' + CAST ( tbl.YEAR as varchar(4) )) as [DATE1]  
from TABLE as tbl
```

and this gives syntax error.
Can anyone tell me, what I should be doing ?

Comment: Based on the use of square braces, I'm removing the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `case` needs an `end`:

```
SELECT (case when tbl.MONTH = '1' then 'JAN' + ', ' + CAST(tbl.YEAR as varchar(4) ))
        end) as [DATE1]
from TABLE tbl;
```

If the values are being stored as numbers, then don't put single quotes around the constant value.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `end`, which is needed to close the `case` statement:

```
case
when tbl.MONTH ='1'
then ('JAN' + ', ' + CAST ( tbl.YEAR as varchar(4) ))
end
as [DATE1] 
from TABLE as tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is by using **`Datename`** Inbuilt function. No need of `CASE statement` to hardcode all the months

```
SELECT Datename(mm, tbl.[MONTH]) + ', '
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tbl.YEAR) AS [DATE]
FROM   TABLE AS tbl
```

or if you are using sql server 2012

```
SELECT Choose(tbl.[MONTH], 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
       + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tbl.YEAR) AS [DATE]
FROM   TABLE AS tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Pradeep's answer, but using a handy little DATENAME fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/188390/405180, and trimming to first 3 chars:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(Datename(MONTH , DateAdd( MONTH , tbl.[MONTH] , -1 )), 3)) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tbl.[YEAR]) AS [DATE]
FROM   TABLE AS tbl
```

TBH, I think from a performance point of view, you're better off using a `CASE tbl.[MONTH] WHEN 1 THEN 'JAN' WHEN ...` approach.