# Convert month number int full month name

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in my table with a bunch of numbers like this:

```
1
2
3
etc...
```

instead of the column outputting numbers I would like it to be full month names like this:

```
January
Feburary
March
etc...
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Just curious if you even looked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Comment: Yeah, I messed up on that one... I knew i have seen it somewhere and could not find it again. Thank you for the help. I did change a bit of the answer just to shorten down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `datename` with increment as your column value

```
select DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month,column,0) -1)
from Table1
```

Comment: @JasonFaulkner also provided the right answer, but I ended up using this. Thank you!