# Extract Month-Year from a unix timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**mytable.timecreated** is a BIGINT column on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database and it contains a unix timestamp.

This query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,mdl_user_enrolments.timestart,'19700101 02:00') as TheDate
FROM mytable
```

gives me the date in this format:

```
2015-05-30 20:30:05.000
```

How do I retrieve just the Month and Year from that timestamp, like this:

```
May 2015
```

The following SQL seems to do the job, but is there a simpler way to do it?

```
SELECT 
    CAST(
        CASE 
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 1 Then 'January'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 2 Then 'February'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 3 Then 'March'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 4 Then 'April'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 5 Then 'May'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 6 Then 'June'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 7 Then 'July'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 8 Then 'August'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 9 Then 'September'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 10 Then 'October'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 11 Then 'November'
            WHEN month(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) = 12 Then 'December'
        END AS NVARCHAR(10))
    + ' ' +
    CAST(YEAR(dateadd(s,timecreated,'19700101 02:00')) AS NVARCHAR(5)) AS MyDate
FROM mytable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `datename()`?

```
select (datename(month, dateadd(second, timecreated, '19700101 02:00')) + 
        datename(year, dateadd(second, timecreated, '19700101 02:00'))
       )
```

I'm leaving `02:00` in this because that is how you phrased your question.  THe correct conversion, though, would use `00:00`, unless you are trying to correct for a time zone.

Also note that the values returned by `datename()` depend on your internationalization settings, so they are not necessarily in English.

Comment: That only gives me the Month portion, but it did put me on the right track. This seems to do what I want:


`SELECT

CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(s,mytable.timestart,'19700101 02:00')) AS NVARCHAR(10))

+ ' ' + 

CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(s,mytable.timestart,'19700101 02:00')) AS NVARCHAR(5))

FROM mytable`

Comment: @luisdev . . . I fixed the answer to include the year.  You can use `datename()` for the year as well, so no conversion is required.

Comment: Yes the 02:00 fixes the time zone (I need UTC+2).

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff
This seems to work for me - and it looks cleaner:

`select (
datename(month, dateadd(second, timecreated, '19700101 02:00'))
+ ' ' +
datename(year, dateadd(second, timecreated, '19700101 02:00'))
)
from ...`

Answer (score 2):

There are some built in `CONVERT` functions you can use. I don't know if there is one for the specific format that you want, but 106 is close enough that can be combined with the `RIGHT` function to get what you want, like this:

```
SELECT
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),mdl_user_enrolments.timestart,106), 8) as MyDate
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using? I would just put a UNIX timestamp in the database and then, using PHP, I would do

```
<?php date("M Y", strtotime($your_unix_timestamp));
?>
```

but then you have to get the data from SQL into PHP so if you're going to be using PHP anyway, it might be easier

Comment: No, not PHP, just plain vanilla SQL run from Management Studio.