# Comparing orders by months in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sales table with 3 columns

```
OrderId, CustomersId, OrderDateTime
```

How to write a T-SQL select query to find number of `orderId`, January2015orders and April2015orders in the results? Thanks!

Should I use union or a case statement or ???

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As written (originally) it is somewhere between too vague and too broad to answer.

Comment: This is a great question someone asked me and I am seeking advise by someone more experienced here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [datepart function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420(v=sql.120).aspx)

If you want orders from the January, April of the year 2015 you could write your query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    count(t.OrderId) as Orders, 
    DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime) as Month
FROM 
    SalesTable t
WHERE 
    datepart(year, t.OrderDateTime) = 2015 
    AND (datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 1 
    OR datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 4)
GROUP BY
    datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime)
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00b7f/25) for a working example

**EDIT:**

If you want to full month name, instead of the number, you could apply one of these solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql). The query would then look like this:

```
SELECT count(t.OrderId) as Orders, DateName(month , DateAdd( month , DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime), -1 ))
FROM SalesTable t
WHERE datepart(year, t.OrderDateTime) = 2015 and 
      (datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 1 or datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 4)
group by datepart(month,t.OrderDateTime)
```

**EDIT2:**
As per your comment, the columns January2015Orders and April2015Orders are mandatory. In this case, you could go with this solution:

```
SELECT count(t.OrderId) as Orders, 
       DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime) as January2015Orders,
       null as April2015Orders
FROM SalesTable t
WHERE datepart(year, t.OrderDateTime) = 2015 and 
      datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 1
group by datepart(month,t.OrderDateTime)

UNION

SELECT count(t.OrderId) as Orders, 
       null as January2015Orders,
       DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime) as April2015Orders
FROM SalesTable t
WHERE datepart(year, t.OrderDateTime) = 2015 and 
      datepart(month, t.OrderDateTime) = 4
group by datepart(month,t.OrderDateTime)
```

The first query selects January2015Orders with its value and April as null. This is followed by a second query, which selects January as null and April2015Orders with its value.

Not pretty, but it (hopefully) renders the correct results. 
[Here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00b7f/38) to play around with

Comment: This helps, and partially works - however need only count(OrderId), January2015orders and April2015orders in the SELECT statement. It cant be just DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime) as Month. - It has to be January2015orders and April2015orders.

Comment: Thanks it got me closest. The only thing missing in yours was COUNT(DatePart(month, t.OrderDateTime)) as January2015Orders

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
select month(OrderDateTime),count(OrderId) from your data group by month(OrderDateTime)
```

It would be good to know If you mean:

> number of orderId as a count ?

Comment: Yes count(orderId).... It's the 2months Jan and April  columns that I feel is challenging part.

Comment: I ran your query but it does not solve the problem of only producing result for count/number of orderId, January2015orders and April2015orders in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [**DATENAME**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) in Sql Server.

like,[**Fiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ce66/5)

```
 SELECT 
    Cast(DATENAME(MONTH, t.OrderDateTime) as Varchar(20))+
    cast(DATENAME(YEAR, t.OrderDateTime) as varchar(4)) as YearMonth,
    count(t.OrderId) as Orders
    FROM SalesTable t
    group by DATENAME(MONTH,t.OrderDateTime),DATENAME(YEAR,t.OrderDateTime)
```