# Can any one please tell me logic behind select DATENAME(month,29*5)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

`select DATENAME(month,29*5)`

Can any one please tell me logic behind the above query.
How it always returns correct month name when provided month number as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will able to explain.

The default year-month-day for any date data type is 1900-01-01. If we consider above select query, it add 29*5 days into default date and gives the MONTHNAME.

```
Select DATENAME(month,29*5)
```

Now understand the `DATENAME`

**DateName** - Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date. Its have different -2 argument and give the different-2 result as per datepart.

> Argument 1 - Is the part of the date to return.
>
> Argument 2 - Is a any date (Is an expression that can be resolved to a
>   time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset
>   value.)

Here we given `month` as a first argument. Which means it return `monthname`.

The calculation of `29*5` gives `145` answer and if we simply cast into date it consider as a days and calculate as `1900-01-01 + 145` and gives the date **1900-05-26 00:00:00.000**.

Means if we get the month of this will give the 5 - MAY as a answer.

Execute this query and check the answer for the above logic.

```
Select DATENAME(month,29*5), (29*5)  , DATENAME(month, '12:10:30.123'), DATENAME(month, getdate()) 
select cast (145 as datetime)

DECLARE @t datetime = '12:10:30.123'; 
SELECT DATENAME(month, 29*5), 145/30.00;
```

Check for further.
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx)

[Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql) (check the @user275683 answer)

Comment: Thanks Ajay for good explanation

Is this method efficient for larger databases?

Comment: @Shardul, what is the meaning of larger databases? what do you want with this statement, Ideally this is the conversion statement, so where you want to apply will effect the performance.  please explain more.

Comment: Larger database in the sense that it may contain millions of records so while fetching these records will this query perform good or it will degrade performance?
Please also suggest efficient method to do this in case large number of records need to be retrieved.

Comment: In general sense, there is not effect comes, but if you say about millions record fetch, it definately impact, right way to do is you must save the date with proper dateformat in datetime column. so while fetching,  nothing to do of casting or convert

Answer (score 2):

`Datetime` values in Sql server are stored on 8 bytes.
The first 4 bytes represents the date and the last 4 byte represents the time.

On the date part, date is stored as the number of days since `1900-01-01`.

On the time part, it's the number of clock ticks since midnight.
There are 300 clock ticks per second, so a tick is 3.33333 milliseconds.
That's also the reason why datetime is only accurate to `.003` of a second.

This query will hopefully help to explain:

```
SELECT  CAST(0 As datetime) As Date_0,
        29*5 As NumberOfDays, 
        CAST(29*5 as datetime) As TheDate,
        DATENAME(month,29*5) As TheMonthName
```

Results:

```
Date_0                      NumberOfDays    TheDate                     TheMonthName
-----------------------     ------------    -----------------------     ------------
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     145             1900-05-26 00:00:00.000     May
```

As for the last part of your question, 29 (28 would work as well) is the magic number here - 30 is too big (May would be returned for 4 and 5) and 27 is too small - (September would be returned for 9 and 10).
Basically i'ts just math - get the number correctly so that each time you double it with any number between 1 and 12 will give you a number of days that sums up to a day that belongs to the correct month.

You can test it yourself using this script:

```
DECLARE @MagicNumber int = 28

;With cte as 
(
    select 1 as num
    union all
    select num + 1
    from cte 
    where num < 12
)

SELECT  num, DATENAME(month, @MagicNumber * num ) As TheMonthName
from cte
```

Just change the value of `@MagicNumber` and see the results you get.

Comment: And I would just add (integer "0" means January 1st)

Comment: @MasterDJon: 1900. Anyway, I've added a more comprehensive explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply want to show the month corresponding to month number then you should have to use like this.

```
  declare @intMonth as int
  set @intMonth = 5    
  Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @intMonth , -1 ))
```