# Slow expression building in SSIS

Tags: ssis, expression

In my SSIS package, I have a variable with expression as below:

```
@[User::ReportMonth]=(MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 1 ? "Jan" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 2 ? "Feb" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 3 ? "Mar" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 4 ? "Apr" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 5 ? "May" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 6 ? "Jun" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 7 ? "Jul" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 8 ? "Aug" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 9 ? "Sep" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 10 ? "Oct" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 11 ? "Nov" :
MONTH(@[User::ReportStartDate]) == 12? "Dec":"")
```

I want to get the report month to be displayed on the report file name, for example Report_Nov2016.txt. I can get the value with the expression above, but the problem is it takes about 2-3 minutes to return the value, and the process makes my Visual Studio 2015 hang as well.

Is there any other solution to handle such problem?

Comment: Possible solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql