# Convert Month Number to Month Name Function on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-view

My good reference has been 
[Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

So far I have:

```
SELECT Detail.ItemCode, SUM(Detail.QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity, Header.OrderDate
FROM Detail INNER 
JOIN rHeader ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= dateadd("m", -4, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode, OrderDate
ORDER BY SUM(Detail.QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

It filters my results and it shows only last four months result from today's month.

I'd like to have each month's sales quantity sum, and its month to name function.

For instance:

```
ItemCode | 10 or October | 11  |  12 |  1     
   PM    |        200    | 200 | 200 | 200
```

> Update: I did try the following line of code, but my date is in the form of 12/26/2016. Is there anyway that I can play with it?? Thank you!

```
 SELECT MonthName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )
```

Comment: Based on your question history, I believe you are using Access as the front and back end. If that is true, then your referenced page in the first sentence is a bad resource. SQL Server and Access are different platforms, using different versions of SQL (the language). They are not interchangeable. Focus on questions with [SQL] *and* [Ms-Access] tags or you are going to get examples with incorrect syntax or functions that don't exist.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Thank you :) Very good point!! You are great! Thanks for the edit!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Access query you should be able to use the [MonthName](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MonthName-Function-c64bcf54-2534-45bc-acef-de80f4a959c4) function to convert a month number (e.g., `10`) into a month name (e.g., `'October'`).

For example, if you have a query that returns a date of birth (DOB)...

```sql
SELECT [DOB] FROM [Clients] WHERE [ID]=1
```

```
DOB
----------
1977-05-15
```

.. you can return the name of the month in which they were born using

```sql
SELECT MonthName(Month([DOB])) AS MonthOfBirth FROM [Clients] WHERE [ID]=1
```

```
MonthOfBirth
------------
May
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I have tried Select MonthName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 ). But I do not have any field to use 'month'. My date field is like 12/25/2016. Could you please give your input on this? Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Much appreciated! Hope you have a great night :)