# SQL Server changing date format 2012

Tags: sql-server

What is the easiest way to turn "2016-01-17 00:00:00:" into just simply "January" (and so on)?

```
SELECT
    VendorName,
    Invoices.InvoiceNumber,
    Invoices.InvoiceDueDate AS InvoiceMonth
FROM
    Vendors,
    Invoices
WHERE
    Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID;
```

[Here is what I am attempting to get from executing in SQL Server:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QerVm.png)

[Here is what I am currently getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCRlo.png)

Comment: Why do you want to return a date as text directly from the database? You should preserve column types in your data-processing steps for as long as possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql  why you were unable to search for that is beyond me.

Comment: Your looking for DateName()  Try  Select DateName(MONTH,'2016-01-17 00:00:00')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti that would just give me the same thing I have wouldn't it? I want it to just print the month name instead of '2016-01-17 00:00:00'

Comment: @jaket578 No, it will return the month name from any given date

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a little confusion

```
SELECT
    VendorName,
    Invoices.InvoiceNumber,
    DateName(MONTH,Invoices.InvoiceDueDate) AS InvoiceMonth
FROM
    Vendors,
    Invoices
WHERE
    Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID;
```

To boot, the JOIN should really look like this

```
From Vendors
Join Invoices on Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip, sorry I am just starting to learn SQL. Also I edited my post so that you could see what I was talking about. @JohnCappelletti

Comment: We call that the old join syntax.