# SQL - Convert date into string

Tags: mysql, date, type-conversion

I have a table with a date column in it ('yyyy-mm-dd'). I want to be take from that column the month of each date and print it out as in 'MMM' style or the full name of the month (E.g 2017-09-22 --> "Sept" or "September")

I know how to extract the month but not how to convert it...i tried something with NAMEDATE that i found in a similar question but i was getting errors... any tips?

Comment: Date conversion functions vary from vendor to vendor. Are you asking for SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: sql...im using it on workbench

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  In MySQL, you want the `date_format()` function (in SQL Server, either `format()` or `convert()`).

Comment: @Kh.Taheri I have tried that as you can see from what I wrote. It didn't work

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give me an example please?

Comment: So, could you post your attempts?

Comment: Please take the time to work out which database you're using, also take the time to write down what you tried and what error you got. These are the first steps to solving it yourself.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I asked for tips not for you to solve it for me! O.o

Comment: That was a tip... a tip that might lead to you solving it yourself

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid oh thanks! how clever of you!!! :)

Comment: You need to write your using MySQL and not SQL. This will give you the correct answers.

Comment: @plaidDK it says that on the tags!

Comment: No - @GordonLinoff asked you, and you said SQL. And that is not the same.

Comment: @plaidDK i said "
 
sql...im using it on workbench" MYSQL Workbench (the program you know?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MONTHNAME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

```
SELECT MONTHNAME('2008-02-03');
        -> 'February'
```

Comment: @GeorgeXReplay if it full fill your requirement then accept it by clicking on right mark under vote count