# How to write an expression that adds text month to numerical value?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which returns number of doors sold in a month from 2 locations. The month is displayed as a value 1-12.... I would like to return `1-Jan`, `2-Feb` etc.

[image: table]

**EDIT**

I am using:
 `datepart(MONTH, DeFactoUser.F_ST_Transaction.STTR_DATE)` to get the month number, I have tried:
 `datepart(MONTH, DeFactoUser.F_ST_Transaction.STTR_DATE) + '-' + datename(MONTH, DeFactoUser.F_ST_Transaction.STTR_DATE)` to get the name appended to the number. I get an error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'September' to data type int.`

Obviously doing something silly.... any clues would be good.

Comment: @GarethD  Linked to a rather old solution.  I suspect OP is on 2012

Comment: If 2012+      format(datefromparts(1,[month],1),'M-MMM')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti see edit

Comment: Even if using 2012+ I would still recommend using the most upvoted answer in the link (not the accepted answer). On a table with 500,000 rows of numbers 1-12, I found that `FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1, i, 1),'M-MMM')` consistently took 2-3 times longer than `CONCAT(i, '-', LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, I, -1 )), 3))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN '1-Jan'
WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN '2-Feb'
WHEN [Month] = 3 THEN '3-Mar'
...
END AS [MonthName]
```

Alternative is using DATENAME:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(1) AS NVARCHAR(2))+'-'+LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH,MONTH(1))),3)
```

This has been asked before: [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

If you do not want a case expression.

Answer (score 2):

If your month column is a date you can use the `DATENAME` function.

If it is just a number you can still use `DATENAME` but simulate the date with `DATEFROMPARTS` e.g.

```
SELECT datename(MONTH,datefromparts(2017,1,1))
```

then just concatenate your number and the name with

```
concat(cast(yournum AS varchar(2)),'-',datename(MONTH,datefromparts(2017,1,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS nvarchar(2))  +'-'+ CONVERT(varchar(3), GETDATE(), 100)
```