# extract month from date as string mm

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to get the month from a date column

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) Month
```

It gives me a number but I need a string like JAN, FEB, etc.

What is the SQL to accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Comment: Firebird has no build in for this, you have to use `case` or `decode`.

Comment: Look at below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Comment: Hello, in fact it seems that DATENAME is not available in Firebird

Comment: @GregViers Why suggest a duplicate that applies to SQL Server?

Comment: @Arun Why suggest a question that applies to SQL Server?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wonder if ICU library maybe has month names for most languages in the world, so perhaps it could be reused as UDF :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The Not easily, and note that UDFs are deprecated and have been (will be) removed in Firebird 4.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function in Firebird that will immediately yield a month name. If you want that, you'll need to write it yourself, for example using a combination of [`extract`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract) and [`decode`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-decode):

```
decode(
    extract(month from datevalue),
    1, 'JAN',
    2, 'FEB',
    3, 'MAR',
    4, 'APR',
    5, 'MAY',
    6, 'JUN',
    7, 'JUL',
    8, 'AUG',
    9, 'SEP',
    10, 'OCT',
    11, 'NOV',
    12, 'DEC')
```

If you use Firebird 3, then you can create a [PSQL function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-psql-funcs) for this:

```
create function monthname(datevalue date) returns char(3)
as
begin
    return decode(
            extract(month from datevalue),
            1, 'JAN',
            2, 'FEB',
            3, 'MAR',
            4, 'APR',
            5, 'MAY',
            6, 'JUN',
            7, 'JUL',
            8, 'AUG',
            9, 'SEP',
            10, 'OCT',
            11, 'NOV',
            12, 'DEC');
end
```

Alternatively, you could try:

```
case extract(month from datevalue)
   when 1 then 'JAN'
   when 2 then 'FEB'
   -- etc
   when 12 then 'DEC'
end
```

Comment: Hi Mark, the code seems to be the solution but I have a problem, I get a message that it cannot convert the data type, I say 1 to 'JAN', If I convert 1 to 1 I get it right.

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull It works for me, what version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull you do not need to CONVERT anything in a straightforward query. It seems you try to integrate this solution into some larger framework of yours, maybe view or something. 
Show the exact query u execute and exact error message

Comment: Hello Mark, I am using version 2.5. The query is: decode(cast(extract(month from date) as int),'1','JAN','2', 'FEV') month, the erro " it is not possible to convert the type of data requested..."

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull 1) the cast to int is unnecessary, and 2) the numerical parameters should be a numerical literal (not a string literal), as shown in my answer. Point 2 shouldn't matter, it works for me if I use a string literal (Firebird 2.5.8, 3.0.3). However, the error message you quote is not a Firebird error message, which may mean your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Mark, decode(extract(month from date),2,2) month - it works. decode(extract(month from date),2,'feb') month - it does not work. I am using a connect via excel powerrpivot.

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull I don't know that, but maybe you're trying to request it as the wrong datatype in that tool?

Comment: It is likely that I am having a data type issue because when I use only numbers it works but when I change to a string it gives me an error. Do you think I can write a code to force the data types to be the same ?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull Given I know nothing about Excel Powerpivot, I really can't answer that.