# SELECT DATEPART, DATENAME or other? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a new query where I would like to add three additional columns (same format):

Week Number (as 08) / Month (as February) / Year (as 2019)

```
SELECT hd.F91 AS [PO Number],
hd.F1032 AS [Trs Number],
hd.F76 AS [Order Date],
hd.F27 AS [Vendor ID],
hd.F334 AS [Vendor Name],
hd.F1127 AS Admin,
hd.F1068 AS State,
hd.F1067 AS Status,
tl.F65 AS Total,
DATEPART(wk,[Order Date]) AS [Week Number],
DATENAME('month',[Order Date]) AS Month,
DATENAME('year',[Order Date]) AS Year,
```

The rest of the data is being pulled from our system but I tried to get these three columns based on an already existing column called Order Date (date format).

Unfortunately, the error below showed up. All suggestions to try would be welcome. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: your wk is not in single quotes, but your month and year are in single quotes.  Use one or the other (not sure which one is correct in MSSQL) but that is your issue

Comment: yeah what type of SQL server are you dealing with here?

Comment: yeah I'm in PostgresSQL it was not available either I used  to_char([order date], 'Month')

Comment: That is clearly SQL Server you are using - including the error message.

Comment: Check this post I think you may have your answer there I dont see something here that you did find your answer, I dont have a Microsoft SQL server installed at the moment so I cannot test i, basically it's this  : DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mydate-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))      ->     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

These functions work in mysql (as was the tag of the question before edited!!!):

```
WEEK([Order Date], 1) AS [Week Number],
MONTHNAME([Order Date]) AS Month,
YEAR([Order Date]) AS Year,
```

change the argument `1` in `WEEK` according to your needs 
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: My bad, I should have added SQLserver, I didn't even know there were different types. These functions do not work on this platform. Thanks for your quick assistance!

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me in postgreSQL
 to_char([order date], 'Month')

Comment: "to_char is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: yeah I didnt know the type SQL engine... we could code that function if you have the rights....

Answer (score 0):

THIS QUESTION WAS ORIGINALLY TAGGED FOR POSTGRES.

The ANSI standard functionality is:

```
extract(week from "Order Date")
extract(month from "Order Date")
extract(year from "Order Date")
```

Postgres supports this standard syntax.

If you want a string, you can use `to_char()`:

```
to_char("Order Date", 'WW')
to_char("Order Date", 'YYYY')
to_char("Order Date", 'Month')
```

Comment: Standard syntax : to_char is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: ANSI standard functionality: Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM