# SQL Server : month name from date column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get the month name from a column?

I have a column `txndate`

```
Select Month(g.Txndate) as Month
```

This returns 1,2,3,4,.....12. How can I get Jan, Feb, Mar, etc?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query

`SELECT DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(Txndate) - 1, '1900-01-01')) MonthName`

Or
 `SELECT FORMAT(g.Txndate, 'MMMM') AS Result`

[Reference](https://database.guide/3-ways-to-get-the-month-name-from-a-date-in-sql-server-t-sql/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()))
```

Or this one (Thanks, [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff))

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3)
```

Customized for your table...

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, g.Txndate)) AS Month
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, g.Txndate), 3) AS Month
```

Result

```
+-------+
| Month |
+-------+
| Mar   |
+-------+
```

Comment: I would use `LEFT()` instead of `CONVERT()`.