# Extracting month number and converting it into month name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I came across a SQL query:

```
select IssuedDate, Convert(char(4), IssuedDate, 0)
from TempTable
```

and this is its output:

```
           IssuedDate            Null
    ----------------------------------
    1964-02-17 00:00:00.0000000  Feb 
    2018-08-28 00:00:00.0000000  Aug 
    2018-08-28 00:00:00.0000000  Aug 
    2018-08-28 00:00:00.0000000  Aug
```

Can anyone please let me know how the `convert` function is working and converting month number to month name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)

Comment: Why not use `DATENAME`?

Comment: As for how it's working, it's using `CONVERT` and a [Date and Time style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles). But it seems odd that it wants the first 3 characters of the month's name, followed by a space.

Comment: @larnu yes that making me confused about its implementation

Answer (score 1):

This is using the default format for convert (the third argument is `0`), which is "mon dd yyyy hh:miAM".  That is, the first three characters in the formatted string are the month abbreviation.

The conversion is to a string with a length of four, it keeps only the first four characters.  That would be the month abbreviation and the following character.

In my opinion, a more sensible approach would be:

```
left(datename(month, issueddate), 3)
```

This at least works for English, where the month abbreviations are the first the characters of the month name.