# Convert Char in "yyyymm" to an actual date formatted as Mon-yyyy?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL Server code that I inherited with a column 'YearMonth' with the value formatted as (202201). It is not currently in a date format, but I would ultimately like to convert the entire column to a date format like Jan-2022 (Mon-Year). Below is the component of the code in question. I removed the lines that aren't pertinent to my question.

```
declare     @CoverageYear   Char(4); -- Month being inserted
declare     @CoverageMonth  Char(2); -- Year being inserted


set         @CoverageYear   =   Year(getdate());                                                                -- Run for the current coverage year
set         @CoverageMonth  =   case when Month(getdate()) <= 9 then '0' + cast(Month(getdate()) as char(1))    -- Run for the current coverage month
                            else cast(Month(getdate()) as char(2)) end; 

select      @CoverageYear+@CoverageMonth as YearMonth
```

Column is not currently in date format, so it would need to be converted.

Comment: what sql are you using?

Comment: What RDBMs are you using? Please add appropriated tag.

Comment: Before you do that, be aware that it can often be more convenient to use the format you have.  If you convert to a date/time type, then it's going to have year/month/day/hour/minute/second, so when you want just year and month, you'll have to use a date function.

Comment: Re-enforcing what @TimRoberts mentioned here, there is no date data type that is only month/year. So it should mostly depends on your use case. If it is mostly visualization purposes you should leave it as is and let whatever consumer handles the formatting. If it is for calculation then you will need to convert to a date type and hence add at least the day to it for the conversion as using functions to extract month/year specially on filtering **might** make your queries slower. If it is only the formatting you can use one of the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/185520/460557

Comment: You would be much better off converting to a date datatype and then changing how you display it only when you need to, ideally in the front end.

Comment: The code you show doesn't include a table/column at all. So your question is asking one thing, but your code is showing another.

Comment: `cast(YearMonth + '01' as date)` will give you a date at the first of the month. `convert(varchar(12), FirstOfMonth, 107)` will format the date as "mmm dd, yyyy". `stuff(MDY, 4, 5, '-')` will then strip out the " dd, " portion and replace it with a dash yielding the desired "mmm-yyyy" format. Put together, the entire expression is `stuff(convert(varchar(12), cast(YearMonth + '01' as date), 107), 4, 5, '-')`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/edeLcM69).

Answer (score 0):

```
select FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(foo, 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(foo, 5, 2), '-01') AS Date), 'MMM-yyyy', 'en-US')
from
(select '202401' as foo) t;
```

We get the year substring, the month substring, concatenate them into a date format, cast the result as date and format accordingly.